# Align react-table last column to the right

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I'm using react-table and I want to align the last column in the table to the right. My strategy has been to apply a custom class of `text-right` to the column. To do this, I've tried overriding `getHeaderProps` in my columns but no luck:

```
const columns = React.useMemo(
  () => [
    {
      Header: 'Name',
      accessor: 'name',
    },
    {
      Header: 'Age',
      accessor: 'age',
      getHeaderProps: () => { className: 'text-right' },
    }
  ]
)
```

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: Why not with CSS?

Answer (score 0):

While looking for an answer to this same question. I figure I could do this.

```
const columns = React.useMemo(
  () => [
    {
      Header: 'Name',
      accessor: 'name',
    },
    {
      Header: 'Age',
      accessor: 'age',
      Cell: (cellProps) => <AgeDisplay {...cellProps} />,
    }
  ]
)

const AgeDisplay = (cellProps) => <div className="text-right">{cellProps.cell.value}</div>;
```